# How to give a line break between buttons

Tags: javascript, html

How to add line breaks between buttons in javascript? I want break tag 
 to be outside of the button elements.

html:

```
<button id="buttonOne"> click one me </button>
<button id="buttonTwo"> click on me too </button>
```

js:

```
var buttonOne = document.getElementById("buttonOne");
var lineBreak = document.createElement("br");
buttonOne.appendChild(lineBreak);
```

gives:

```
<button id="buttonOne"> click one me <br> </button>
<button id="buttonTwo"> click on me too </button>
```

what I want is:

```
<button id="buttonOne"> click one me </button> 
<br>
<button id="buttonTwo"> click on me too </button>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use CSS? `display: block` Than there is no need for the br and for JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var buttonOne = document.getElementById("buttonOne");
var lineBreak = document.createElement("br");
buttonOne.parentNode.insertBefore(lineBreak, buttonOne.nextSibling);
```

```html
<button id="buttonOne"> click one me </button>
<button id="buttonTwo"> click on me too </button>
```

Try:

```
var buttonOne = document.getElementById("buttonOne");
var lineBreak = document.createElement("br");
buttonOne.parentNode.insertBefore(lineBreak, buttonOne.nextSibling);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`after()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/after) should do it:

```js
var buttonOne = document.getElementById("buttonOne");
var lineBreak = document.createElement("br");
buttonOne.after(lineBreak);
```

```html
<button id="buttonOne"> click one me </button>
<button id="buttonTwo"> click on me too </button>
```